# Elasticsearch query shows more data than it has

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

In my contains field I have "xr" data and "xra","xrb","xrc" seperately. When I make query for the count of "xr" elasticsearch does not return me 1, it returns 4. How can I manage it?

This is my query

```
"aggs": {
                "Group1": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "method.keyword",
                        "include": ".*POST.*",
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "Group3": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "contains.keyword",
                                "size": 11593,

                            }
                        }

                    },

                        }
```

Comment: can you show your index mapping and full search query

Comment: This is my mappings( it is kinda scattered but hope you understand): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/v5KjB8NqHf/  

Above query is my full search query. I am using python-elasticsearch library to make this query.

Comment: You did not provide the full query, only the aggregation part. Plus we need sample data to try to reproduce your problem. Can you provide example documents to help us understand what your mean by "In my contains field I have "xr" data and "xra","xrb","xrc" seperately" ?

Comment: Any chance to solve problem with this information? Cause I use it inside python-elasticsearch library and don't know how to attain what you want